# Feedback on WebGL fragment shader used in Freeciv WebGL

Tags: three.js, webgl, glsles

[Freeciv WebGL 3D](https://play.freeciv.org) is a open source strategy game which uses the Three.js 3D engine.
I'm interested in some feedback to improve the WebGL GLSL shaders which I have developed for this game.

I have included the terrain fragment shader here, which I'm most interested in feedback on. How can I make this more efficient?

```
<!-- GLSL Fragment Shader for Freeciv-web -->
<script id="terrain_fragment_shh" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec3 vNormal;


uniform sampler2D terrains;
uniform sampler2D maptiles;
uniform sampler2D borders;
uniform sampler2D roadsmap;
uniform sampler2D roadsprites;
uniform sampler2D railroadsprites;

uniform bool borders_enabled;

uniform float map_x_size;
uniform float map_y_size;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vPosition_camera;


float sprite_pos0_x = 0.0;
float sprite_pos0_y = 0.75;
float sprite_pos1_x = 0.25;
float sprite_pos1_y = 0.75;
float sprite_pos2_x = 0.5;
float sprite_pos2_y = 0.75;
float sprite_pos3_x = 0.75;
float sprite_pos3_y = 0.75;
float sprite_pos4_x = 0.0;
float sprite_pos4_y = 0.5;
float sprite_pos5_x = 0.25;
float sprite_pos5_y = 0.5;
float sprite_pos6_x = 0.5;
float sprite_pos6_y = 0.5;
float sprite_pos7_x = 0.75;
float sprite_pos7_y = 0.5;
float sprite_pos8_x = 0.0;
float sprite_pos8_y = 0.25;
float sprite_pos9_x = 0.25;
float sprite_pos9_y = 0.25;
float sprite_pos10_x = 0.5;
float sprite_pos10_y = 0.25;
float sprite_pos11_x = 0.75;
float sprite_pos11_y = 0.25;
float sprite_pos12_x = 0.0;
float sprite_pos12_y = 0.0;
float sprite_pos13_x = 0.25;
float sprite_pos13_y = 0.0;

float terrain_inaccessible = 0.0;
float terrain_lake = 10.0/255.0;
float terrain_coast = 20.0/255.0;
float terrain_floor = 30.0/255.0;
float terrain_arctic = 40.0/255.0;
float terrain_desert = 50.0/255.0;
float terrain_forest = 60.0/255.0;
float terrain_grassland = 70.0/255.0;
float terrain_hills = 80.0/255.0;
float terrain_jungle = 90.0/255.0;
float terrain_mountains = 100.0/255.0;
float terrain_plains = 110.0/255.0;
float terrain_swamp = 120.0/255.0;
float terrain_tundra = 130.0/255.0;

float is_river_modifier = 10.0/255.0;

// roads
float roadtype_1 = 1.0/255.0;
float roadtype_2 = 2.0/255.0;
float roadtype_3 = 3.0/255.0;
float roadtype_4 = 4.0/255.0;
float roadtype_5 = 5.0/255.0;
float roadtype_6 = 6.0/255.0;
float roadtype_7 = 7.0/255.0;
float roadtype_8 = 8.0/255.0;
float roadtype_9 = 9.0/255.0;
float roadtype_all = 42.0/255.0;

// railroads
float roadtype_10 = 10.0/255.0;
float roadtype_11 = 11.0/255.0;
float roadtype_12 = 12.0/255.0;
float roadtype_13 = 13.0/255.0;
float roadtype_14 = 14.0/255.0;
float roadtype_15 = 15.0/255.0;
float roadtype_16 = 16.0/255.0;
float roadtype_17 = 17.0/255.0;
float roadtype_18 = 18.0/255.0;
float roadtype_19 = 19.0/255.0;
float railtype_all = 43.0/255.0;

float beach_high = 54.5;
float beach_blend_high = 52.5;
float beach_blend_low = 50.0;
float beach_low = 44.0;
float blend_amount = 0.0;

float mountains_low_begin = 98.0;
float mountains_low_end = 100.0;
float mountains_high = 115.0;

vec3 ambiant = vec3(0.27, 0.55, 1.);
vec3 light = vec3(0.8, 0.6, 0.7);

vec2 texture_coord;


void main(void)
{

    vec4 terrain_type = texture2D(maptiles, vec2(vUv.x, vUv.y));
    vec4 border_color = texture2D(borders, vec2(vUv.x, vUv.y));
    vec4 road_type = texture2D(roadsmap, vec2(vUv.x, vUv.y));

    vec3 c;
    vec4 chosen_terrain_color;

    if (terrain_type.g == is_river_modifier) {
      beach_high = 50.5;
      beach_blend_high = 50.25;
    }

    /* Set pixel color based on tile type. */
    if (terrain_type.r == terrain_grassland) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_plains) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos11_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos11_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_lake) {
      if (vPosition.y < beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos9_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos9_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_coast) {
      if (vPosition.y < beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
        if (fract((vPosition.x + 502.0) / 35.71) < 0.018 || fract((vPosition.z + 2.0) / 35.71) < 0.018) {
          chosen_terrain_color.rgb = chosen_terrain_color.rgb * 1.45;  // render tile grid.
        }

      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_floor) {
      if (vPosition.y < beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos4_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos4_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
        if (fract((vPosition.x + 502.0) / 35.71) < 0.018 || fract((vPosition.z + 2.0) / 35.71) < 0.018) {
          chosen_terrain_color.rgb = chosen_terrain_color.rgb * 1.7;  // render tile grid.
        }
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_arctic) {
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_y);
      chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_desert) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_forest) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_hills) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_jungle) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos8_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos8_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_mountains) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_swamp) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos12_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos12_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else if (terrain_type.r == terrain_tundra) {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos13_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos13_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    } else {
      if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high ) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos11_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos11_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      } else {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        chosen_terrain_color = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      }
    }

  c = chosen_terrain_color.rgb;

  if (vPosition.y > mountains_high) {
      // snow in mountains texture over a certain height threshold.
      blend_amount = ((3.0 - (mountains_high - vPosition.y)) / 3.0) - 1.0;

      vec4 Ca = texture2D(terrains, vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_y));
      vec4 Cb = texture2D(terrains, vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_y));
      c = mix(Ca.rgb, Cb.rgb, (1.0 - blend_amount));
  } else if (vPosition.y > mountains_low_begin) {
      if (vPosition.y < mountains_low_end) {
        vec4 Cmountain = texture2D(terrains, vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_y));
        c = mix(chosen_terrain_color.rgb, Cmountain.rgb, smoothstep(mountains_low_begin, mountains_low_end, vPosition.y));
      } else {
        // mountain texture over a certain height threshold.
        vec4 Cb = texture2D(terrains, vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos10_y));
        c = Cb.rgb;
      }
  }


  if (fract((vPosition.x + 502.0) / 35.71) < 0.018 || fract((vPosition.z + 2.0) / 35.71) < 0.018) {
    c = c - 0.085;  // render tile grid.
  }


  /* render the beach. */
  if (vPosition.y < beach_high && vPosition.y > beach_low) {
    texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_y);
    if (vPosition.y > beach_blend_high) {
      blend_amount = ((beach_high - beach_blend_high) - (beach_high - vPosition.y)) / (beach_high - beach_blend_high);
      vec4 Cbeach = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      c = mix(chosen_terrain_color.rgb, Cbeach.rgb, (1.0 - blend_amount));

    } else if (vPosition.y < beach_blend_low) {
      blend_amount = (beach_blend_low - vPosition.y) / 6.0;
      vec4 Cbeach = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord) * 2.0;
      c = mix(chosen_terrain_color.rgb, Cbeach.rgb, (1.0 - blend_amount));

    } else {
      vec4 Cbeach = texture2D(terrains, texture_coord);
      c = Cbeach.rgb;
    }
  }

  /* Roads */
  if (road_type.r == 0.0) {
      // no roads
  } else if (road_type.r == roadtype_1 && road_type.g == 0.0 &&  road_type.b == 0.0) {
      // a single road tile.
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_y);
      vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
  } else if (road_type.r == roadtype_all) {
      // a road tile with 4 connecting roads.
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_y);
      vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_y);
      t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_y);
      t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_y);
      t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
  } else if (road_type.r == railtype_all) {
      // a rail tile with 4 connecting rails.
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_y);
      vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_y);
      t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_y);
      t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_y);
      t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
      c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
  } else if (road_type.r > 0.0 && road_type.r < roadtype_10) {
      // Roads
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_2 || road_type.g == roadtype_2 || road_type.b == roadtype_2) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_3 || road_type.g == roadtype_3 || road_type.b == roadtype_3) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_4 || road_type.g == roadtype_4 || road_type.b == roadtype_4) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_5 || road_type.g == roadtype_5 || road_type.b == roadtype_5) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos4_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos4_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_6 || road_type.g == roadtype_6 || road_type.b == roadtype_6) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_7 || road_type.g == roadtype_7 || road_type.b == roadtype_7) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_8 || road_type.g == roadtype_8 || road_type.b == roadtype_8) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_9 || road_type.g == roadtype_9 || road_type.b == roadtype_9) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos8_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos8_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(roadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
  } else if (road_type.r >= roadtype_10 && road_type.r < roadtype_all) {
      // Railroads
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_10 && road_type.g == 0.0 &&  road_type.b == 0.0) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos0_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_12 || road_type.g == roadtype_12 || road_type.b == roadtype_12) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_13 || road_type.g == roadtype_13 || road_type.b == roadtype_13) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos2_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_14 || road_type.g == roadtype_14 || road_type.b == roadtype_14) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos3_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_15 || road_type.g == roadtype_15 || road_type.b == roadtype_15) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos4_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos4_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_16 || road_type.g == roadtype_16 || road_type.b == roadtype_16) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos5_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_17 || road_type.g == roadtype_17 || road_type.b == roadtype_17) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos6_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_18 || road_type.g == roadtype_18 || road_type.b == roadtype_18) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos7_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
      if (road_type.r == roadtype_19 || road_type.g == roadtype_19 || road_type.b == roadtype_19) {
        texture_coord = vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos8_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos8_y);
        vec4 t1 = texture2D(railroadsprites, texture_coord);
        c = mix(c, vec3(t1), t1.a);
      }
  }


  /* Borders*/
  if (borders_enabled && !(border_color.r > 0.546875 && border_color.r < 0.5625 && border_color.b == 0.0 && border_color.g == 0.0)) {
    c = mix(c, border_color.rbg, 0.55);
  }

  /* specular component, ambient occlusion and fade out underwater terrain */
  float x = 1.0 - clamp((vPosition.y - 30.) / 15., 0., 1.);
  vec4 Cb = texture2D(terrains, vec2(mod(map_x_size * (vUv.x / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_x , mod((vUv.y * map_y_size / 4.0), 0.25) + sprite_pos1_y));
  c = mix(c, Cb.rgb, x);

  float shade_factor = 0.28 + 1.0 * max(0., dot(vNormal, normalize(light)));

  gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(c * shade_factor, ambiant, (vPosition_camera.z - 550.) * 0.0001875);

}

</script>
```

All the shaders can be found here:
https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv-web/tree/develop/freeciv-web/src/main/webapp/javascript/webgl/shaders

I'm particularly interested in feedback to improve performance, how to improve the terrain shader in terrain_fragment_shader.js, and if there are any general patterns I could use to improve the shaders.

Comment: I voted to close, but only because your question currently doesn't fit the StackOverflow Q&A format: one question at the time, and questions need to be answerable (so no "please provide feedback" question, you'd need to change them to concrete questions with a discrete answer). Please don't take it as a criticism of your work, as it seems like an awesome project! If you adapt your questions to be a better fit I'd love to try and answer some.

Comment: @Paul-Jan Agreed. And definitely not a criticism! This is amazing work, but your question doesn't fit very well here and I don't think you'll see good responses. I'd recommend posting on code review instead :) And again, great work!

Comment: Maybe it's more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think the question just needs to be edited/reworded. First off you need to **post the shaders in the question itself**. Linking offsite means the moment those shaders change the question becomes irrelevant. Second you need to ask for something specific, not just feedback. For me simply asking "How can I make this more efficient" might be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question based on your feedback.